# Perform generic search using Spring Data JPA on my DB

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, nativequery, spring-data-jpa-datatables

For that, I have created a query like this

```
@Query(value="SELECT"+ retreiveCol +"FROM"+tableName+"WHERE"+condition, nativeQuery = true)
    public Object genericSearch(@Param("retreiveCol") String retreiveCol,@Param("tableName") String tableName,@Param("condition") String condition);
```

But getting this error:

> Hibernate:
> SELECTFROMWHERE
> [2m2021-10-23 09:33:09.574[0;39m [33m WARN[0;39m [35m7684[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m SQL Error: 42001, SQLState: 42001
> [2m2021-10-23 09:33:09.574[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m7684[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECTFROMWHERE[*]"; expected "SET, SAVEPOINT, SCRIPT, SHUTDOWN, SHOW"; SQL statement:
> SELECTFROMWHERE [42001-200]
> [2m2021-10-23 09:33:09.586[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m7684[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8081-exec-3][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [SELECTFROMWHERE]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement] with root cause

> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "SELECTFROMWHERE[*]"; expected "SET, SAVEPOINT, SCRIPT, SHUTDOWN, SHOW"; SQL statement:
> SELECTFROMWHERE [42001-200]

Comment: Pretty obvious I would have thought - the SQL you are generating is `SELECTFROMWHERE` i.e. no spaces, no column names, no table name. And that is an extremely unsafe way to query the database, it leaves you completely open to an SQL injection attack.

Comment: @DaleK My requirement is to create a query to fetch the data from any table of DB, I have 1200 tables in my DB. So, how can I achieve this by using Spring DATA JPA. Please help me out

Comment: I have no idea, but fixing your syntax errors as I explained would be a good start.

Comment: @DaleK Okay, I'll try that, but tell me is my approach is correct?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can do that with Spring Data JPA. Your repository must be typed and bound to a specific entity.

Most importantly, your approach will cause a major security issue since it makes SQL injections very easy.

If you're looking for a solution to build dynamic search requests, based on infinite criteria, I suggest investigating [spring-boot-starter-data-search](https://github.com/commerce-io/spring-boot-starter-data-search).

You can find a demo for jpa [here](https://github.com/commerce-io/spring-boot-starter-data-search-jpa-demo)

---

*Disclaimer: I'm a contributor of spring-boot-starter-data-search*